# gitlab ci: "No files to upload" for job artifacts

Tags: gitlab-ci

This is my first time trying to generate a gitlab-ci job artifact. My ci script generates a csv file that I want to download as an artifact in the job. The yaml file is as below.

```
   unittest:
      script:
        - cd unittest
        - bash ci-test.sh
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - /*.csv
        when: always
        expire_in: 1 day
```

I obtained an error msg like this.

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: /*.csv: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload
```

I have confirmed that the generated csv report is there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Paths are relative to the project directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifactspaths). With that said, you cannot access files outside of the project directory, so `/*.csv` is incorrect.

If files are in the project, then just set path relative to the project, e.g. if you have it in `reports` folder, then make path equal `reports/*.csv`

Answer (score 4):

You can also set your project directory path to the artifacts path:

```
  artifacts:
      paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR
      expire_in: 1 week
```

This way in your code if you are not specifying any particular path for any file then it will always be in Project Directory and GitLab runner will be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your output file to $CI_PROJECT_DIR

An example:

```
test:
  stage: quality
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  script:
    - cd /app
    - coverage run -m pytest
    - coverage report
    - coverage xml -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/coverage.xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s([.\d]+)%/'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - coverage.xml
    reports:
      cobertura:
        - coverage.xml
```

Answer (score -3):

When I asked my tech-lead about it, he said "it's looks like a runner nas not internet connection", then I restarted my job and got success.